# sliding elements onto the page using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have got 3 buttons that slide in from the right and end up on the left of a page, but for some reason they wont line up like they should do. I have used `.animate({left: 100 + 'px'})` all buttons but with different `left` offsets so that they appear diagonally across the page.

For some reason they line up wierd. The first and second seem to line up diagonally but the third one doesn't continue the diagonal line I was going for.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dyDfY/8/)

Comment: Note: no need for the `'px'`, jQuery automatically deals with it.

Comment: "_Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance._"

Comment: i hope i have been more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregarding the fact that I had to visit the external site to check out the relevant code, the solution to your problem is quite simple. It's a CSS issue.

```
#slideWrapper #bradfordOnAvonButton {
    top: 60px;
    left: 1000px;
}

#slideWrapper #turleighButton {
    top: 30px;
    left: 1000px;
}
```

Swap those `top`s and your code is fine.

On a sidenote, it's redundant to select the buttons with two IDs since they already have an ID of their own. `#turleighButton` is sufficient.

Comment: sorry i cant get used to the code layout on this webpage so i thought it would be easier to post on jsfiddle and thanks that worked out fine :)

Comment: @JakeJääskeläinenHazelwood If so, please consider marking this answer as correct. It would help me gain some more rep. ;)